# WordPress All in One SEO not finding/displaying the title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with a WordPress site that is not reading the meta title correctly. I am using the All in One SEO plugin.

In the header.php file I have

```
<title>
    <?php //Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed
    global $page, $paged;
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );
    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) echo " | $site_description";
    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'continuum' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
    ?>
</title>
```

WordPress always confuses me; all I want to do is display the title that is input into the All in One SEO thing via the admin area.

Comment: What do you mean by "reading" exactly? What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: Do you use a caching layer? I would also check what is the code of 'oneSEO' is doing?

Comment: This is my first time working with word press, how do I know if a caching layer has been configured? Also not sure on what the oneSEO is doing.

In my opinion word press code is a mess with no clear structure after working with the MVC for the past few years

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "meta title"? What happens/doesn't happen that you're expecting to happen? What does the output look like, and how do you want it to look? What are you expecting the All In One SEO plugin to do?

Comment: The meta title ie browse title. It has been entered via the admin area and is not being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you called `wp_head();` in your header.php file?

it should be placed just before the closing of the header `</head>`

Answer (score -1):

Block-Bots-htaccess.txt (copy this code paste into all htaccess), you can use All in One SEO > Enable File Editor > Edit the htaccess